# wso2 install button is not working on mobile application management

Tags: mobile, wso2, app-manager, entgraiot

I published an application through app publisher on iot-server.

I gave the proper right to the user to install the application.

URL follows:https://entgra.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/IoTS360/pages/352786583/Installing+an+Application+on+a+Device

[image]

when I tried to click on the install button, there is no popup display on the screen to install the application.

Can you help me to resolve the issue?

Comment: You need to have a device enrolled in the system to have those buttons enabled

Comment: @InoshPerera Is it possible for the enrolled device without an android agent?

for, user login into the browser, it should display application to him for download.